# Delphi can't terminate I/O processes correctly

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Delphi doesn't write last few lines.
A procedure calls `writeToText(a1, a2, ...)` for each line.

```
type
  TQuerySQL = class
    public
      Constructor Create;
      Destructor Destroy; override;
      procedure writeToText( plate:String; positionNo:String; newOdometer:String; oldOdometer:String);
  end;

var
  tconnect : TADOConnection;
  tquery : TADOQuery;
  F_Text: TextFile;

implementation

Constructor TQuerySQL.Create;
begin
  AssignFile(F_Text, 'results.txt');
  ReWrite(F_Text);
  tquery := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
  tconnect := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
  tconnect.Close;
  tconnect.ConnectionString := 'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=SOFT20150911;';
  tconnect.ConnectOptions := coConnectUnspecified;
  tconnect.LoginPrompt := False;
  tconnect.Open;
  ShowMessage('starting');
end;

Destructor TQuerySQL.Destroy;
begin
  tquery.Close;
  tquery.Free;
  tconnect.Close;
  tconnect.Free;
  CloseFile(F_Text);
  ShowMessage('finished in destructor');
  inherited Destroy;
end;
  
procedure TQuerySQL.writeToText( plate:String; positionNo:String; newOdometer:String; oldOdometer:String );
begin
  Write(F_Text, 'UPDATE POSITIONS SET');
  Write(F_Text, ' ODOMETER = '+oldOdometer);
  Write(F_Text, ' WHERE');
  Write(F_Text, ' LABEL = '''+plate+'''');
  Write(F_Text, ' AND POSITIONNO = '''+positionNo+'''');
  Write(F_Text, ' AND ODOMETER = '+newOdometer+';');
  WriteLn(F_Text);
end;
```

Sample Output:

> UPDATE POSITIONS SET ODOMETER = 904068,1 WHERE LABEL = '34 XXX 11' AND POSITIONNO = '12110126'AND ODOMETER = 904092,2;
>
> UPDATE POSITIONS SET ODOMETER = 904068,1 WHERE LABEL = '01 AL 101'AND POSITIONNO = '165556'AND ODOMETER = 904092,2;
>
> UPDATE POSITIONS SET ODOMETER = 904148,7

Comment: Why isn't your F_Text a field of your TQuerySql class?  Having it as a stand-alone global variable seems to invite accidental misuse of it.  Also, you are not specifying a path when you do the AssignFile.  Btw, your title should read "I can't ..." not  "Delphi can't ..." ;=)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I assume that you are seeing the message "finished in destructor" on screen?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe some part of your code accesses the `F_Text` variable from outside the `TQuerySQL` class in between the `Create` and the `Destroy` calls.

The same happens if you run together more than one instance of the class `TQuerySQL` as long as `F_Text` is declared in the `var` section of the unit.

If there's no reason why this should happen, you may consider to make it `private`:

```
type
  TQuerySQL = class
    private
      F_Text: TextFile;
    public
      Constructor Create;
      Destructor Destroy; override;
      procedure writeToText( plate:String; positionNo:String; newOdometer:String; oldOdometer:String);
  end;
```

The same applies for:

```
tconnect : TADOConnection;
tquery : TADOQuery;
```

To make shure this doesn't happen for mistake in the same unit, you may also consider to add the `strict` keyword to the `private` section of the class.

---

In addition to the above, it's not generally considered a good practice to perform tasks other than the objects freeing in a destructor.

My advice is to consider to use an extra public method to perform the closing operation and let the destructor do its job.

```
public
  procedure writeToTextClose;
```

. . .

```
procedure TQuerySQL.writeToTextClose;
begin
  CloseFile(F_Text);
  tquery.Close;
  tconnect.Close;
  ShowMessage('write to text finished');
end;

destructor TQuerySQL.Destroy;
begin
  tquery.Free;
  tconnect.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

The task can be accomplished like this:

```
var
  qSql: TQuerySQL;

. . .

qSql := TQuerySQL.Create;
try

  try
    //here multiple calls to writeToText take place
    qSql.writeToText(a1, a2, ...);

  finally
    //ensure CloseFile(F_Text) at least
    qSql.writeToTextClose;
  end;

finally
  //ensure objects freeing
  qSql.Free;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try flushing the buffer for the file before closing it:

```
Flush(F_Text);
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that this is necessary. I don't think it is, and it looks like a guess.

Comment: Flush flushes Delphi’s buffer, not the operating system’s buffer, it may be a timing issue from OS shutting down the application. It is a guess for that is the only thing really left to look at.